# Local component data change Vuex state when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I've a component called `EditUser.vue` which is linked to a router system using vue router, this is the definition of the route for this component

```
{
 path: "/users/:id/edit",
 name: "Edit User",
 props: true,
 component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName "edit-user" */ "@/views/EditUser.vue"),
 beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
   if (!store.getters.isLogged) next("/");
   else next();
 }
},
```

Pretty straightforward with props enable because it needs to get the user id.

The component itself is this

```
<template>
<main class="h-creen p-3">

      <Input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        label="name"
        v-model="user.name"
        required
      />
</main>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import Input from "@/components/Input.vue";

export default {
  name: "EditUserView",

  props: {
    id: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    }
  },

  components: {
   Input,
  },

  data: () => ({
    user: {},
   }),

  async beforeMount() {
    // TODO move into router file
    if (this.users.length <= 0) {
      this.$router.push("/users");
    }

    this.user = this.users.find(user => user.id == this.id);
  },

  computed: mapState(["users"])
  };
</script>
```

I've omitted the useless parts, this code replicate the problem anyway. `<Input>` is just a wrapper for a label and an input with some styling, nothing magic there.

The problems is that if I type something into the input I expect that `this.users` gets modified, which it happens, but it should not modified the same record inside the Vuex state, but that happens and I don't get why. In other words if I edit the name using the input, this modification gets propagated on the state, thus being rendered in other views, but it shouldn't since it's a local data.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not 100% sure but you map your users to this.users. Since objects are pass by reference in javascript your changes probably propagate back to your vuex

Comment: *it shouldn't since it's a local data* - it's not local data because you're using global state. As it was already mentioned, user object is passed by reference. Please, explain how exactly the component is supposed to work. Should changes be submitted back to global state via submit button or else?

Comment: @EstusFlask yes my intention is that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results in assigning with a reference to existing object:

```
this.user = this.users.find(user => user.id == this.id);
```

When `user.name` property is changed with `v-model` two-way binding, the respective nested object is modified in `users`.

Data should be either shallowly copied to be local (deep copy may be necessary depending on the case):

```
this.user = {...this.users.find(user => user.id == this.id)};
```

Then `this.user` should be copied back to `this.users` when needed.

Or the component shouldn't have its own `user`, it can contain separate fields:

```
  <Input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    label="name"
    v-model="name"
    required
  />
```

`name`, etc. can be copied back to `this.users` when needed.

Comment: Interesting. I swear I read somewhere that `find()` was assigning by value but apparently I was so wrong. I'll try this fix and come back here to accept this answer.

Comment: No built-in function deep-copies an object, this is expensive and does more harm than good, you wouldn't be happy if it were copied by value because this way they would be different objects every time, `this.users.find(...) !== this.users.find(...)`. It's by reference by design in JS - unless it's a primitive.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance  I'm still a novice in Javascript, thanks for this helpful advice. I learned something valuable today